# My owl Carousel is not working

Tags: jquery, html, owl-carousel

I tried this given below code but the images is shown in list view.  Here i have tried changing everything like i added jquery code of loop and all but nothing worked.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="OwlCarousel2-2.2.0/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="OwlCarousel2-2.2.0/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="owl-carousel sliderImgs owl-loaded">
        <div class="item"><img src="images/1.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="images/2.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="images/3.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="images/4.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="images/5.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="images/6.jpg"></div>
        <div class="owl-controls">
            <div class="owl-nav">
                <div class="owl-prev">prev</div>
                <div class="owl-next">next</div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-dots">
                <div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
                <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
                <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="OwlCarousel2-2.2.0/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the js file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
loop:true,
margin:10,
nav:true,
responsive:{
    0:{
        items:1
    },
    600:{
        items:3
    },
    1000:{
        items:5
    }
}
});
});
</script>
```

Here is the css file

```
img
{
/*display: block;*/
height: 50%;
width: 50%;
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Define "nothing worked"

Comment: @WesFoster nothing worked means the images are shown in list form as it would have shown without the plugin.

Comment: Where you initiating owl carousel? you have to initiate it with `$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel()`.

Comment: Any console errors? Are the styles and scripts being loaded? Are the element identifiers matching the ones called in the javascript file? You've left out so much information that you're making it very difficult for someone to volunteer their time to help you.

Comment: @azs06 it was just above the jquery file and yes i started the code with $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel() only.

Comment: @WesFoster No sir, no errors. and yes, identifiers are matching.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle with working owl carousel, https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/hhzdv3xL/, as mentioned above look for error/warning in console, also check documentation to be sure that you are following right instruction.https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Comment: @azs06 i know it's working, as shown in documation of official site. But my code is not working and that's why i asked the problem here. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: Please include rest of your codes for the slider, it would be difficult for anyone to give a solution based on assumption.

Comment: @azs06 added rest of the codes. Although, i have cross-checked, but please see if i have added any wrong plugin.

Comment: Edit your question, find the `<>` button and use it to create a [mcve]. Could you also explain why your question was tagged `css` and `javascript`?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Sorry for the tag.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thanks for the anwer. I was placing my own script at wrong place.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Load the resources in this specific order (see working example at the bottom):

**In `<head>`**

1. `assets/owl.carousel.min.css`
2. `assets/owl.theme.default.min.css`

**In `<body>`**

3. Place a `<div>` with classes `owl-carousel` and `owl-theme` and any other custom classes of your choice, where you want your carousel to be displayed. Any other specific carousel classes ***should not*** be added (i.e. `owl-loaded`).
4. Inside this div place `<div>`s containing images, like in the example below, without the class `item` (it will be added by the carousel). You could add custom classes if you need them for styling particular slides but no `owl` specific classes.
   Don't place any other carousel specific markup, (like prev/next buttons or bullets). They will be added by the carousel, according to your initialization options.
5. `jquery.min.js` (make sure it loads and path is correct)
6. `owl.carousel.min.js` (from `/dist` folder, make sure it loads)
7. your own `<script>`, containing the call to initialization.

**Important aspects:**

- 5, 6 and 7 ***must*** be loaded in this order. They could be placed before 3 and 4, or even included in the `<head>` tag. However, if you place them inside `<body>`, below the fold, your page will seem to load faster. In effect, it will load exactly the same, but the visible elements rendered when you load the page will load after 5,6 and 7 are loaded, so it will appear to load slower.
- if you load 1 and 2 inside `<body>`, using `<style>` tags, which is not recommended and if they are placed after the carousel markup, it is possible some browsers will render a quick un-styled version of your carousel, before parsing the CSS. That's why it is better to load them in `<head>`.
- Place `type="text/javascript"` on all your `JavaScript` `<script>` tags (`jQuery` is a `JavaScript` library).

Working example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/400/300.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/238/400/300.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/239/400/300.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/240/400/300.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/241/400/300.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/242/400/300.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/243/400/300.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/400/300.jpg"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
   loop:true,
   margin:10,
   nav:true,
   responsive:{
     0:{
       items:1
     },
     600:{
       items:3
     },
     1000:{
       items:5
     }
   }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: If you're using Vue, here's another thing to check: is your code for step #7 ("your own <script>, containing the call to initialization.") inside of a function that you're passing to `Vue.nextTick`, inside of your Vue component's `created` method? It should be. When using Vue, you need to initialize things there instead of using the normal jQuery `$(document).ready`.